# locate entries with given value for a multi-dimensional array and visualize it

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I have an array with shape `[5000, 255,255,1]`. 5000 represents the number of images; (255,255) are the size of an image

Most of the entry values are 0 while some entry values are 1. How can I know the index or position of these entries with value of 1.

Finally, if it turns out that [100,:,:1] has some entries of 1. I would like to show this specific image/matrix as a heatmap. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is `np.where`, when you feed it an array that has values 0 or non-zero, it will give you all the indices that are non-zero in the form off n 1D arrays for a n-dimentional input. So that code will give you a set of all the images that contain non-zero pixels:

```
i,x,y,_=np.where(arr)
print(set(i))
```

Then you can display the image you want like that :

```
plt.imshow(arr[list(set(i))[0],:,:,0],cmap='hot')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is an error message  plt.imshow(arr[set(d1)[0],:,:,0],cmap='hot')
TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing